# query multiple attribute in a table with single attribute in another table

Tags: postgresql

I can't explain my problem in English well. So I write my problem in a personal way.

```
user_id    name      surname
1          john      great
2          mary      white
3          joseph    alann


event_id   official_id  assistant_id    date
1          1            2               2017-12-19
2          1            3               2017-12-20
3          2            3               2017-12-21
```

I want to get names at the same time when I query an event. I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM event a, user b WHERE a.official_id=b.user_id AND a.assistant_id=b.user_id
```

When I use "OR" instead of "AND" gives me cartesian result. I want the result like:

```
event_id   off_id off_name  asst_id asst_name    date
1          1      john      2       mary         2017-12-19
2          1      john      3       joseph       2017-12-20
3          2      mary      3       joseph       2017-12-21
```

Comment: I found a solution:


select a.event_id, a.official_id, b.name, a.assistant_id, c.name from public.event a
inner join public.user b on a.officialuserid=b.userid
inner join public.user c on a.assistantuserid=c.userid

is it right way to query?